# EndlessOS to Windows 10

Tags: linux

I've bought a new Acer laptop and it has come with pre-installed EndlessOS. I want to get rid of it and install Windows 10. I have Windows 10 ISO file.
Can someone please guide me through the installation process?
Installing Windows on a Linux machine is a bit confusing

Answer (score 1):

This short guide assumes you don't want to preserve any data already on the laptop.

1. **Start off:** Boot off Windows installable media (DVD or bootable flash disk).

   If you want to create a flash disk using the ISO, [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) will do that for you. Just check *Quick format* and *Create a bootable disk*, then use the button next to it to select the ISO.
2. **Purge the hard disk:** When Windows installer boots, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. A command line window will appear. Type `diskpart` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   `diskpart` will take a moment to start, you'll see a `DISKPART>` prompt when it's ready. Type `list disk` and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Take note of number next to your hard disk (if you have more than one storage device connected, flash drive included, it will be listed there too). Type `select disk 0` (replace `0` with the number listed next to hard disk) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Run `list disk` again, an asterisk should appear next to hard disk.

   Type `clean` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `exit` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Close the command line window.
3. **Install Windows:** Windows installer is pretty straightforward, you can just keep clicking *Next*.

   You may want to create additional partitions to keep some data off system disk, you can do that on the partitioning screen using the *New* button. When creating the first partition, Windows may add additional small ones automatically. That's okay, just don't install to them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Windows DVD is in the drive.

First of all you will need to get into the Bios or Boot Menu. The Bios is the brain of the motherboard and is separate from Linux OS or Windows OS.

Bios is probably displayed as a  the black screen that comes up when starting the computer. You can usually get there by using the F1-F12 keys or delete or escape. What you want is to set the boot order or boot menu to boot from your windows CD. Then run through the Windows installation wizard.

CAUTION: When installing another OS you could end up erasing all the data already on the computer.

Comment: You need to give more information to provide a solution to OP